# Unable to edit text in Draft.js editor when setting it with data from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, draftjs

I created a blog app using Draft.js and I'm a bit stuck on the EditPost.js file. I am able to import the data from an existing post into the editor but unable to edit the text at all. The cursor just stays in the same place and won't even go to the end of the text. Keep in mind I am saving the editor text to the database as HTML, and then converting it back to text after the post is loaded. Here is all the code, except for the imports:

```
export default function EditPost() {

    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        title: "",
        body: "",
        image: "",
    })
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
    const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
    const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState("");
    const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const { id } = useParams();

    //Draft.js code

    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
        () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
    );

    const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);

    //function for converting post body to HTML
    useEffect(() => {
        let html = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
        setConvertedContent(html);
        setFormData({ ...formData, body: convertedContent });
    }, []);

    //function for setting the image to the image URL
    useEffect(() => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, image: imageURL });
    }, [formData, imageURL]);

    // console.log(convertedContent);

    //END

    //Image upload code

    function handleImageChange(event) {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
        // setFormData({ ...formData, image: event.target.files[0].name });
    }

    const handleUpload = () => {
        if (!file) {
            alert("Please upload an image first!");
        }

        const storageRef = ref(storage, `/files/${file.name}`);

        // progress can be paused and resumed. It also exposes progress updates.
        // Receives the storage reference and the file to upload.
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const percent = Math.round(
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                );

                // update progress
                setPercent(percent);
            },
            (err) => console.log(err),
            () => {
                // download url
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                    console.log(url);
                    const urlToString = url.toString();
                    console.log(urlToString);
                    setImageURL(urlToString);
                    console.log(imageURL);
                });
            }
        );
    };

    //END

    //Get post code

    //function for getting the post
    useEffect(() => {
        const getPost = async () => {
            const docRef = doc(db, 'posts', id);
            try {
                const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
                setPost(docSnap.data());
                console.log(post);
                const text = htmlToText(post.body, {
                });
                console.log(text);
                setText(text);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        };
        getPost();
        return () => {
            // this now gets called when the component unmounts
        };
    }, [id, post]);

    //END

    //Submit form code

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (formData.title === "") {
            alert("Please enter a title");
            return;
        }
        if (formData.body === "") {
            alert("Please enter some body copy");
            return;
        }
        const postDocRef = doc(db, 'posts', id);
        try {
            await updateDoc(postDocRef, {
                title: formData.title,
                body: formData.body,
                image: formData.image,
                created: Timestamp.now(),
            })
            alert("Post updated successfully!")
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //END

    return (
        <div>
            <Menu />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Blog App</h1>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <input
                        name="title"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        defaultValue={post.title}
                        onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, title: e.target.value })}
                    />
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                    {/* <textarea
                        name="body"
                        placeholder="Enter text here"
                        value={formData.body}
                        onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, body: e.target.value })}
                    ></textarea> */}

                    <Editor
                        editorState={EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(text))}
                        onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
                        wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                        editorClassName="editor-class"
                        toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
                    />

                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <input
                        value=""
                        name="image"
                        type="file"
                        accept="image/*"
                        onChange={handleImageChange}
                    />
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        value="Upload Image"
                        onClick={handleUpload}
                    >Upload Image</button>
                    <p>{percent} % uploaded</p>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                    >Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div >
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by:

1. Using a separate function for converting HTML back to text.
2. Removing formData from the dependency array.
3. Adding post.body to the dependency array.
4. Changing editorState to editorState={editorState}.

Having formData in the dependency array was causing an infinite loop which was preventing me from typing anything new into the editor.

Here is my updated code:

```
export default function EditPost() {

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        title: "",
        body: "",
        image: "",
    })
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
    const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
    const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState("");
    const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

    const { id } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    //Draft.js code

    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
        () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
    );

    const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);

    //function for converting the HTML back to text
    const htmlToDraftBlocks = (html) => {
        const blocksFromHtml = htmlToDraft(html);
        const { contentBlocks, entityMap } = blocksFromHtml;
        const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocks, entityMap);
        const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
        return editorState;
    }

    //function for converting post body to HTML
    useEffect(() => {
        let html = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
        setConvertedContent(html);
        setFormData({ ...formData, body: convertedContent });
    },);

    //function for setting the image to the image URL
    useEffect(() => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, image: imageURL });
    }, [imageURL]);

    //END

    //Image upload code

    function handleImageChange(event) {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }

    const handleUpload = () => {
        if (!file) {
            alert("Please upload an image first!");
        }

        const storageRef = ref(storage, `/files/${file.name}`);

        // progress can be paused and resumed. It also exposes progress updates.
        // Receives the storage reference and the file to upload.
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

        uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const percent = Math.round(
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                );

                // update progress
                setPercent(percent);
            },
            (err) => console.log(err),
            () => {
                // download url
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                    console.log(url);
                    const urlToString = url.toString();
                    console.log(urlToString);
                    setImageURL(urlToString);
                    console.log(imageURL);
                });
            }
        );
    };

    //END

    //Get post code

    //function for getting the post and setting the editor state
    useEffect(() => {
        const getPost = async () => {
            const docRef = doc(db, 'posts', id);
            try {
                const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
                setPost(docSnap.data());
                setFormData({ ...formData, title: post.title });
                setEditorState(htmlToDraftBlocks(post.body));
                setImageURL(post.image);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        };
        getPost();
        return () => {
            // this now gets called when the component unmounts
        };
    }, [id, post.body]);

    //END

    //Submit form code

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (formData.title === "") {
            alert("Please enter a title");
            return;
        }
        if (formData.body === "") {
            alert("Please enter some body copy");
            return;
        }
        const postDocRef = doc(db, 'posts', id);
        try {
            await updateDoc(postDocRef, {
                title: formData.title,
                body: formData.body,
                image: formData.image,
                created: Timestamp.now(),
            })
            alert("Post updated successfully!")
            navigate("/dashboard");
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //END

    return (
        <div>
            <Menu />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Blog App</h1>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <input
                        name="title"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        defaultValue={post.title}
                        onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, title: e.target.value })}
                    />
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                    <Editor
                        editorState={editorState}
                        onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
                        wrapperClassName="wrapper-class"
                        editorClassName="editor-class"
                        toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
                    />

                    <br></br>
                    Featured image:
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <img
                        className="post-image"
                        src={`${imageURL}`}
                    />
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <input
                        name="image"
                        type="file"
                        accept="image/*"
                        onChange={handleImageChange}
                    />
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        value="Upload Image"
                        onClick={handleUpload}
                    >Upload Image</button>
                    <p>{percent} % uploaded</p>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                    >Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div >
    );
};
```